# PHP form not updating mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have virtually no programming experience and trying this first project, I am a bit stuck on how to update the database, so I click on edit and the correct record gets loaded into the edit screen update.php

When I click update, I get the message from updated.php saying that the database has been updated, but the database does not get updated, when I display the records they are the same as before the update, thanks in advance for all your help.

the following code:

```
update.php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
$objDB = mysql_select_db("teldirdb");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM teldir where id = '$id' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)
?>

<form id="FormName" action="updated.php" method="post" name="FormName">
<table width="448" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="fname">fname</label></td>
<td><input name="fname" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["fname"];?>">    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="lname">lname</label></td>
<td><input name="lname" maxlength="30" type="text" value="   <?=$objResult["lname"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="tel">tel</label></td>
<td><input name="tel" maxlength="15" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["tel"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="adress1">adress1</label></td>
<td><input name="adress1" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["adress1"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="adress2">adress2</label></td>
<td><input name="adress2" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["adress2"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="pcode">pcode</label></td>
<td><input name="pcode" maxlength="8" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["pcode"];?>">  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="email">email</label></td>
<td><input name="email" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["email"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="lastcontactdate">lastcontactdate</label></td>
<td><input name="lastcontactdate" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["lastcontactdate"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="" type="submit" value="Update"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>

updated.php
<?php
header('Refresh: 5; URL=view11.php');
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","2fudge") or die(mysql_error());
$objDB = mysql_select_db("teldirdb");

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$fname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fname"]));
$lname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lname"]));
$tel = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["tel"]));
$adress1 = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["adress1"]));
$adress2 = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["adress2"]));
$pcode = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pcode"]));
$email = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]));
$lastcontactdate = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastcontactdate"]));

$rsUpdate = mysql_query("UPDATE teldir
SET  fname = '$fname',  lname = '$lname',  tel = '$tel',  adress1 = '$adress1',  adress2 = '$adress2',  pcode = '$pcode',  email = '$email',  lastcontactdate = '$lastcontactdate'
WHERE id = '$id' ");

if($rsUpdate) { echo "Successfully updated"; } else { die('Invalid query: '.mysql_error()); }
```

Comment: Why doesn't anyone use prepared statements? It's killing me.

Comment: You have [a major security hole](http://bobby-tables.com/) and are using `mysql_*` functions which are marked as deprecated in the PHP manual.

Comment: `echo` your query, and check it is as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Your form does not send id parameter. Try adding following line to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id ?>" />
```

Or alternatively, change

```
<form id="FormName" action="updated.php" ...
```

to

```
<form id="FormName" action="updated.php?id=<?= $id ?>" ...
```

As of now your query evaluates to

```
(...) WHERE id=''
```

which is a valid SQL query (therefore not rising an error) but achieves nothing (more specificaly, changes the data in the row where there is no id set)

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is, that there is no field `id` in your form, hence no `$_REQUEST['id']` in `updated.php`, leading to a query

```
UPDATE teldir ... WHERE id = ''
```

Add a hidden field with the id to your form:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?=$objResult["id"];?>
```

And then wait for being hacked... ;-)

Seriously, check Quentin's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your are getting a value for $id?
For $id you are using $_REQUEST['id'], but I didn't see you saving/passing the id value anywhere, for example you can add a hidden field where you save the id of the query and then get that value with $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all make sure that your query is really working either test the query on phpmyadmin or any database manager that you're using.
- Second, don't directly use `$_GET['id']` in a query. You can use prepared statements for this which is available for mysqli and PDO. Don't use mysql API its already in the process of depreciation http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php
- Third , read up [phptherightway](http://www.phptherightway.com/) to make sure you're on the correct path of learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
$objDB = mysql_select_db("teldirdb");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM teldir where id = ".$id." ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
?>
<form id="FormName" action="updated.php" method="post" name="FormName">
<table width="448" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">

<?php
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {
?>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$objResult['id'];?>"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="fname">fname</label></td>
<td><input name="fname" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["fname"];?>">    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="lname">lname</label></td>
<td><input name="lname" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["lname"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="tel">tel</label></td>
<td><input name="tel" maxlength="15" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["tel"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="adress1">adress1</label></td>
<td><input name="adress1" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["adress1"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="adress2">adress2</label></td>
<td><input name="adress2" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["adress2"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="pcode">pcode</label></td>
<td><input name="pcode" maxlength="8" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["pcode"];?>">  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="email">email</label></td>
<td><input name="email" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["email"];?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="150" align="right"><label for="lastcontactdate">lastcontactdate</label></td>
<td><input name="lastcontactdate" maxlength="30" type="text" value="<?=$objResult["lastcontactdate"];?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="" type="submit" value="Update"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

**UPDATE.PHP**

```
<?php
header('Refresh: 5; URL=view11.php');
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","2fudge") or die(mysql_error());
$objDB = mysql_select_db("teldirdb");

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$fname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fname"]));
$lname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lname"]));
$tel = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["tel"]));
$adress1 = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["adress1"]));
$adress2 = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["adress2"]));
$pcode = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pcode"]));
$email = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]));
$lastcontactdate = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastcontactdate"]));

$rsUpdate = mysql_query("UPDATE teldir SET  fname = '".$fname."',  
                                            lname = '".$lname."',  
                                            tel = ".$tel.",  
                                            adress1 = '".$adress1."',  
                                            adress2 = '".$adress2."',  
                                            pcode = ".$pcode.",  
                                            email = '".$email."',  
                                            lastcontactdate = '".$lastcontactdate."' WHERE id = ".$id." ");

if($rsUpdate) { 
    echo "Successfully updated"; 
} else { 
    die('Invalid query: '.mysql_error()); 
}
```